# Mining software and miners verifications and how accept transactions

Tags: transactions

I'm looking how the mining software works and how miners can verify the transactions and how they can accept transactions or not, and I have some questions:

What software use miners to accept transactions when they find a block, their mining software or the Bitcoin client software?

I'm searching information about Bitcoin and I don't know how miners can verify transactions, but I read here that miners that find a block can accept the transdactions that they want, but if they are "bad" or "malicious" miners, they can accept invalid transactions (double spending transactions). When this "bad" or "malicious" miner accepts the transaction this validation is broadcasted over the network to be confirmated?

Sorry for my english. If someone don't understand something of you need to explain more some questions, please reply me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to mining.

The leading approach nowadays is to use Getblocktemplate.  The [wiki page for that](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate) includes a relatively easy to understand example.

There is an implementation in Python called [python-blkmaker](http://gitorious.org/bitcoin/python-blkmaker).

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your answer.

But I need to know hoy miner accepts transactions practically, because if you are mining in a pool, is the pool that chooses what transactions accept and what no, but if you are a solo miner and you find a block I don't know if you need the API or what is necessary.

I haven't so much knowledge in programming languages and it's complicated for me to understand all of that.